# Vector calculus and parameterising line integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, vector-analysis

> Verify Stokes’s theorem for 
>   $F=z^2\mathbf{i}+5x\mathbf{j}$ and $S: 0\le x\le1,\; 0\le y\le1,\; z=1,\,$
>   where $C$ is the closed curve enclosing the surface $S$.

I know how to compute Stokes Theorem and I think I know how to do the surface integral however I'm really struggling with how to parameterise the line integral. Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case, it is just easier to compute the line integral directly instead of parametrizing it. The curve C is a square. So you can integrate along each line separately.

Comment: If I do it this way (thank you I wouldn't have spotted that) then I get -5 however for my surface integral I got +5 can you see which would be right and which wrong as I cant seem to find where I've made a mistake

Comment: Don't worry! I transversed around the circle the wrong way!